# Reducing the expression to more simplified expression

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, summation

Can the following expression be reduced to some more simplified expression?

> $\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{n-a + m-j}{n-a} \times \binom{a-1 + j}{a-1}$

n,m and a are some positive constants with a < n and k < m.

Answer (score 0):

Maple 16 writes it in terms of hypergeometric functions:
 $${n-a+m\choose n-a}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,-m;\,-n+a-m;\,1)}-{n-a+m-k-1
\choose n-a}{a+k\choose a-1}
{\mbox{$_3$F$_2$}(1,k+1+a,-m+1+k;\,k+2,-n+a-m+k+1;\,1)}$$